# Adb shell command ocassionally hangs from command line

Tags: android, shell, xamarin, android-emulator, adb

We have a Xamarin test application, that we run automatically from command line on macOS Sierra. Before it we automatically launch Android emulator from command line. As Android emulator we use x86 emulator, accelerated with Intel HAXM. The script for emulator launching looks in the following way:

```
function isEmulatorReady {
    pathToSDK=$1
    #Check that emulator is booted by checking that boot animation is stopped
    $pathToSDK/platform-tools/adb wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim | grep -m 1 stopped
}

androidSDK=~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
$androidSDK/platform-tools/adb kill-server
$androidSDK/platform-tools/adb start-server
$androidSDK/tools/emulator -avd Android_Accelerated_x86 -wipe-data -partition-size 512 &
emulatorPID=$!
until isEmulatorReady $androidSDK; do
    sleep 1
done

#launch application and wait for end

kill $emulatorPID
```

Ocassionally `adb wait-for-device shell getprop` command hangs and script can't detect that emulator is booted, while Android emulator is successfully booted and works. I don't know how to deal with it. The restart of adb server at the beginning doesn't help actually.